# Some notification tones only shows up for certain apps?

Tags: notifications, 4.3-jelly-bean, sony-xperia

Let's say WhatsApp app. When I try to change notification tones for WhatsApp, some ringtones show up which are not shown when I change device's notification tones.
For example in Sound Picker, **only one tone named Xperia** is shown when I try to change the device's ringtone whereas in WhatsApp, Sound Picker shows **two tones named Xperia**. There are still more like that. How can I make those tones visible for all the apps?

Comment: Do the duplicate tones are same sounds or different?.and do you have tones stored in the `Ringtones` directory?

Comment: They only share the same name but sounds totally different.  No I don't have any extra tones in that directory except two Hangouts tones.